# Unable to get property 'CategoryColor' of undefined or null reference

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

When trying to set the Categorization to a mail, I am getting the below error.

**Unable to get property 'CategoryColor' of undefined or null reference**.

The requirement set 1.8 is supported and the Permission is set to ReadWriteMailbox.

Have also tried to manually give the name of the color(Example: Red) , but then this error occurs

**Error: Sys.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
Parameter name: color**

The method used to set the Category is

```
var masterCategoriesToAdd = [
{
    "displayName": "Urgent!",
    "color": Office.MailboxEnums.CategoryColor.Preset0
}
];

Office.context.mailbox.masterCategories.addAsync(masterCategoriesToAdd, function (asyncResult) {
if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
    console.log("Successfully added categories to master list");
} else {
    console.log("masterCategories.addAsync call failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
}
});
```

Is there any working example where this is set ? I couldn't find any online.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get and manage the categories for a mailbox
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mastercategories?view=outlook-js-1.8

Then use this to apply the existing categories (from above) to the item.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.categories?view=outlook-js-1.8#addasync-categories--callback-

These are the category colors definitions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailboxenums.categorycolor?view=outlook-js-1.8

Comment: Hi Team, Thanks for the quick response. But still the same error. Updated the question with the snippet used.

Comment: Your snippet work as is for me.  Are you using office.js from https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js?   Have you tried to check the value for Preset0, say console.log(Office.MailboxEnums.CategoryColor.Preset0)?  Could you also tell us whether you are using Outlook desktop or OWA (Outlook in browser), and the version of Outlook you are using?

Comment: Hi Team, Yes the JS is loaded from CDN. It worked for me if change the Category value to like this..   `var newCategory = [
    {
        "displayName": "New Category",
        "color": "Preset15"
    }
]; `

Comment: This is interesting.  Office.MailboxEnums.CategoryColor.Preset0 just defines "Preset0".  I suspect the js file is somehow outdated,  Have you checked the value of console.log(Office.MailboxEnums.CategoryColor.Preset0)? If it is still a problem, are you using Outlook desktop on windows or MAC or OWA and what version?  I also suggest trying to clear browser cache.

Comment: Hi Team,  console.log(Office.MailboxEnums.CategoryColor.Preset0) --> Preset0 and i always refer the JS from the CDN. I am using OWA on windows

Comment: Hey, Could you share with us the exact URL that you're hitting for office.js? It would be something of the type: appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js.

Comment: @AhmedVali can you also log Office.MailboxEnums.CategoryColor object in console and see what all values it contains?
The expected values are :
{None: "None", Preset0: "Preset0", Preset1: "Preset1", Preset2: "Preset2", Preset3: "Preset3", …}

Comment: Hi Team, The office.js url is - https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js and if i log Office.MailboxEnums.CategoryColor , it is coming as [Object Object].